# What are the differences between IE6 and IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

The title says it all. I havn't found a satisfyingly exhausting list on the internet anywhere else. [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=Whats+the+differences+between+IE6+and+IE7%3F&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) doesn't yield anything that I'm happy with.

I guess I'm looking for the differences in **everything** associated with both browsers, including (but definitely **not** limited to):

- CSS
- HTML rendering
- JavaScript engine
- Web compatibility
- Bugs & hacks

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page on IE7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7#Features) has a big list of changes from the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

The [What's New in Internet Explorer 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649487%28VS.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN also has an extensive list on the differences between the different Internet Explorer versions, including IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, IE6 and IE5 don't support all the newer versions of languages, like HTML 4 & 5 and the later version of flash and CSS. Drives progammers crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The only 1 important difference is:

IE6 is nothing but a huge pain for web-designers. IE6 must die!

You have no idea how much a pain it is to design a website which works perfectly under Firefox and IE7,8 then find out it's totally broken under IE6, because IE6 is too dumb to compile the code....

Web-designer have to work extra just for the sake that a small percentile, however small, of users to be able to view the website with IE6.

Comment: Actually, I do have an idea how much of a pain it is, since I am a web developer and I work for a corporation whose standard is IE6. And yes, I agree IE6 must die as well!